# how to include a data URI in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, file, form-data

I have a `<form>` element in my `<html>` where the user can put one image:

```
<input type="file" name="imageUpload" accept="image/png|image/jpg|image/jpeg|image/svg+xml" data-type="picture" value="">
```

I made a javascript function which resizes the image (with a canvas) and compress it with the `.toDataUrl` function

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9);
```

the problem is that the form have many options, and the user should continue to modify the form, so I'm trying to find a way to reinject the compressed image into the form (without if possible using the FormData object).

UPDATE (LOGS) :

```
Original file size: 765.533203125kb / height: 1365px / width: 2048px

Width maximum: 800px | Height maximum: 1400px
--------------- After resize ---------------
|Width :800px | Height :533.203125px | Ratio :0.390625 |
--------------------------------------------

New file size: 181.3740234375kb (blob object)

-------------- New file --------------

Blob { size=185727,  type="image/jpeg",  slice=slice()}
```

What is the way to do it ?
Or is there a better workaround ?

Comment: In point of fact, a data URL is never "compressed" compared to the binary image file.

Comment: And I don't think you can "reinject" the base64 string as an actual image in the forms input, you'd have to send it as a string in a hidden input or something, and as noted above by Blazemonger that image wouldn't be compressed at all, it would probably be "bigger" in bytes, even if it's "smaller" in dimensions.

Comment: @adeneo I haven't tried it but this looks like it could be done: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: @Blazemonger @adeneo I updated my question with the logs of my functions, there is first a resize wich resize the image, and then with the `canvas.toDataURL` there is little reduction of the quality (The graphists have a bad habit to upload really large images)

Comment: But by calling `canvas.toDataURL` you get a Base64 string back, and that would generally be 25% "bigger" in the amount of bytes it takes to store the same image! Even if it's resized in the canvas and you save a few bytes on that, it doesn't seem like something that would make a very big difference on the actual amount of bytes being transmitted ?

Comment: @adeneo Look at the updated question, I have put the logs of the image size (after reconvert the dataurl into a blob object), for the images which size are above 1mb, the save can be really great

Comment: Well okay then, you can send the blob with ajax and FormData.

Comment: A few questions: What are you doing on the server? Are you wanting to do only a regular form submit, or can you roll your own upload body? Are you concerned about the upload or the storage size? You may get better traffic/feedback also if you change your title, to "how to include a data URI in a form" or something similar.

Comment: @barry-johnson Done, thanks ! Yep I'm concerned about the upload size, because after that the images will be used in another application which is used by a tablet with a really poor hardware, so the smallest the image is, the better the tablet will works

Comment: @adeneo That is exactly the way I try to avoid, because the form is modified in many javascript functions, so I don't know exactly where to declare the FormData

Comment: @GilleQ.- You say that you are concerned about upload size because "after that" the image will be used on limited hardware. The reason I asked is that you may find it easiest to simply take the image as it is via the upload form and then do the resize on the server side, using GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick, most probably through an adapter lib for your server-side tech of choice. You would still end up with the smaller size image for the lower-end hardware consuming the images.

Comment: @barry-johnson That's not a bad idea and I'll probably do that if I don't find any other solution, but I really wanted to compress the image in the client-side, for saving some cpu usage of the server. Thanks for the library name anyway !